# Clean architecture: share same models/entities with different layers

Tags: android, kotlin, architecture, clean-architecture

In my clean architecture Android app setup, I have own Gradle module for each layer (data, domain, presentation). I also have own models/entities for each layers, which are converted from one layer to another using mappers. This leads to situation where I have a lot of kotlin data classes, representing basically same thing, but in different layer. This does not sound right to me.

Simple example:

**Data layer** - Android library module

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class BuildingEntity(
    @Json(name = "u_id")
    val id: String,

    val name: String,

    val latitude: Double,

    val longitude: Double,

    @Json(name = "current_tenants")
    val tenants: List<TenantEntity>? = null
)
```

**Domain layer** - Pure Kotlin module

```
data class Building(

    val id: String,

    val name: String,

    val location: CoordinatePoint,

    val tenants: List<Tenant>? = null
```

**Presentation layer** Android app module

```
data class BuildingModel(

    val id: String,

    val name: String,

    val location: LatLng,

    val tenants: List<TenantModel> = listOf()
)
```

`BuildingEntity` is fetched from external network api.

This nicely separates each modules from each other, but in my app I have a lot of different entities with nested structures. So I end up writing a lot of kotlin data classes and mappers.

How I can simplify this? Can I remove `Building` class and use `BuildingEntity` on data and domain layer? Just convert `BuildingEntity` to `BuildingModel` on presentation layer?

Im trying find practical answers, how people are solving this kind of problem, not ending up to writing tons of data classes and mappers?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In my domain module I have my models as interfaces (Kotlin allow us to have vals inside interfaces), the implemenations in data module and no models in presentation at all.

Take a look at this small sample:

domain:

```
interface IUserModel {
    val id: String
    val name: String
}

interface UserRepository {
    fun getUserDetails(id: String): IUserModel
}
```

data:

```
@Entity
data class UserEntity(
    @SerializedName("userId")
    override val id: String,
    override val name: String
) : IUserModel

class UserRepositoryImpl(val userDao: UserDao) : UserRepository {

    override fun getUserDetails(id: String): IUserModel {
        return userDao.getUser(id) //userDao.getUser returns a UserEntity
    }
}
```

presentation:

```
class UserDetailsViewModel(val userId: String, val userRepository: UserRepository) : ViewModel() {
    val userData: LiveData<IUserModel> = MutableLiveData()
    fun getUserData() {
        (userData as MutableLiveData).postValue(userRepository.getUserDetails(userId))
    }
}
```

No mappers, no tons of data classes.

I have a couple of projects with this sctructure and sometimes a mapper is needed (convert network models to database entities) but the verbosity is widely reduced using interfaces as models in domain.

Comment: That looks nice! Only problem I can see in my case is that I would like to use some android type objects at least on presentation layer objects, like LatLng. My domain gradle module is kotlin only, so I can not use android stuff there.

Comment: Well, yo can allways use extension functions to accomplish that.
In your presentation: 


fun Building.getPositionLatLon() = LatLon(location.lat,location.lon)

It is just a proposal, if it becomes to complex you can allways create a mapper ;)

Comment: Yeh, thanks! Im already using extension functions to convert my models to another, they are pretty handy.

Comment: Yes they are awasome. I hope you can find a good use for domain models as interfaces as I did. Cheers

Comment: Now when i progressed a bit using this patter, I faced problem when passing my model to another activity via intent. So my model needs to implement Parcable, but as the model (interface) is defined in data layer (pure kotlin module), I can not use Parcable there. Maybe I just implement Parcable in data layer models, and just cast the interfaces in presentation layer to Parcable. This sounds bit hackish though.

Comment: Hum you are right, I haven't faced that issue since I only send ids via intent but sometimes you need to send full models. Nevertheless your solution sounds good to me. I will look deeper in that issue.  Cheers

Comment: @FredyMederos if your presentation model is a combination of multiple domain models how do you handle those? Ex: You have a list of products and some products in your shopping cart. You want to show if the item is added to the cart or not. In this case, the data comes from two different entities. If we had a model for presentation model we could combine them.

Answer (score 10):

Actually, it's right the way you are doing it. To make an app totally Clean you should have different representations of you entities in each layer, and convert them with mappers. This allow you to only change the mappers when you need to change some entity.

For example you may receive some data from the server that you don't want to be shown in UI, so you don't have it in your presentation entity. Another example would be if you want to change an argument name in the data entity. If you access it directly from presentation, you will need to change all the accesses. Instead, if you have mappers, the only thing you have to do is to change the mapper.

Obviously, Clean Architecture is a complex one, that get more sense in big and long time projects, where changes may arise more often. So, it's okay if you want to get rid of doing lot of code if you are doing a little app. In this case i will advice you to use the same entity for Domain and Presentation, and keep mappers for data ones, because as data depends on API, that changes doesn't depend on you, and you would get some benefits from mappers.

Comment: Finding the balance between what is required for the project and what is the "recommended way" of doing something is an art in itself. But it is an important aspect of development. It is finding that balance between doing it quickly and correctly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation. I totally agree with you but I have a question about mappers. My domain module consumes the data module to retrieve data from cache or remote and I have separate models for those modules. I need only one mapper to map entity to domain model, so which module should I put that mapper in?

Comment: Domain module should not know any other module so the mappers should be in data module (as it knows both entities). 
Just as clarification be careful with dependencies. If you are using Android you can divide project in modules and specify in gradle which module depends on each other. That way you will not put any dependency in domain module so you will not be able to put mappers in it even if you want to.

Comment: If you want to retrieve any resource identifier from your data class, Presentation layer is required. You can´t access to the context because is pure Kotlin module

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but I would like to contribute a bit.

So, yes this is clean architecture by the book. If you want to "break" the architecture, then I would suggest you to drop the Presentation Models, and use the Domain models instead.

However, there are cases that a data model(entity) contains information that is not needed in the presentation layer. There you need a different model in the domain, and presentation layer. Do not pass information that is not needed!