# Is it ok to use interfaces as domain models instead of data classes on Android using Kotlin? (Clean Architecture and Domain Driven Design)

Tags: android, kotlin, dns, mapping, clean-architecture

I'm trying to apply clean architecture on my android projects, but it is quite complex, now I'm stuck on this, according to Uncle Bob you should use a model for every layer (domain, data, presentation - in this case), so, typically we create a data class for the domain layer, let's say "Movie":

```
data class Movie(
    private val id: Int = 0,
    private val name: String = "",
    private val imageUrl: String = ""
)
```

So, later in our presentation layer we should have a model to be able to retrieve data from the network, we'll name it MovieDto and it looks like this:

```
data class MovieDto(
    @Json(name = "id")
    private val id: Int = 0,
    @Json(name = "name")
    private val name: String = "",
    @Json(name = "image_url")
    private val imageUrl: String = ""
)
```

Then every time we fetch data using Retrofit we should be getting a MovieDto object in return, but our MovieRepository in our domain layer looks this way:

```
interface RepositoryMovies {
    suspend fun getMovie(id: Int): Movie
}
```

With the previous code we already stablished a contract agreeing to always return a Movie object (remember that inner layers should not know anything about outter layers, so our repository doesn't even know a MovieDto class exists), in order to be able to return a Movie object the repository should use a mapper to convert/map the MovieDto object comming from Retrofit to a Movie object. To avoid all of that I used an interface as my domain model, let me show you:

```
interface IMovie {
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val imageUrl: String
}
```

The only thing we have to do next is to implement the IMovie interface on our MovieDto class:

```
data class MovieDto(
    @Json(name = "id")
    private val id: Int = 0,
    @Json(name = "name")
    private val name: String = "",
    @Json(name = "image_url")
    private val imageUrl: String = ""
) : IMovie
```

Now our repository should return a IMovie interface instead:

```
interface RepositoryMovies {
    suspend fun getMovie(id: Int): IMovie
}
```

With no need of mappers but still forcing "domain rules" by implementing the IMovie interface. I ask you to point me in the right direction, maybe I'm not seeing that this approach is not as flexible or scalable as I tought, what approach would you use? please feel free to comment any pros and cons of each approach.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: There's a discussion here about how `interface` might favor us a lot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53509766/3763032 and here: https://rainbowcake.dev/best-practices/simplification/#mapping-less

Comment: Nice, I'll read them, thank you!